# Question on the usage of pour

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées

In the following sentence:

> Mais il ne l’aborda pas, et se contenta de sortir un peu après elle pour lui faire voir qu’il n’y avoit que faire quand elle n’y étoit pas.

I do not understand the above structure for what is the verb follows "elle" in "elle pour lui faire voir..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Elle* is related to what precedes it, not what follows.

*Sortir un peu après elle*: To go out a bit after her.

*Pour lui faire voir*: To let her see...

Comment: Does the rest mean "to let her see that there is nothing to do when she was not there"?

Comment: Yes, that there *was* nothing to do. These verb endings are archaic.